# ¿Obtener el value de un input y guardarla en variable php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

espero y puedan ayudarme!!, requiero sacar el value de un input y
 guargdarla en variable php!!, este es el codigo que llevo, esta comentado!!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--el id que esta en el a es dinamico, en este ejemplo lo pongo asi para no confundir, y paso el id de este a un input desde jquery con la funcion actualizar(this), posteriormente ya tengo el value de este input y requiero guardar en variable php para realizar una consulta-->
<a class=""  type="button" href=""  id="22"  onclick="actualizar(this)" >ok  </a>
 <input type='text' name='id_riesgo' class="id_riesgo" id='inries' />
<script>
   function actualizar(elemento){
 var id =elemento.id;
 var ok =$("#inries").val(id);

}

</script>
```

Comment: A que te refieres con sacar el value? la propiedad o el valor del input cuando contenga algo?

Comment: Para guardarla en una variable php, necesitas pasar el valor al servidor, ya sea usando una forma o Ajax.

Comment: el valor que se llena automáticamente con la función, se llena por medio de el id "inries"

Comment: sin utilizar POST! ,pasar el valor la servidor  te refieres a un $_REQUEST

Comment: Puedes utilizar POST o GET o algun otro metodo.  Lo importante es que mandes el valor al servidor.